# How to open an uploaded PDF-file using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue.js code to upload and delete files:

```
export default {
    name: "FileUpload",
    methods: {
        addFile() {
            if (this.multiple) {
                let files = _.concat(
                    this.files,
                    Array.from(this.$refs[this.label].files)
                );
                this.$emit("update:files", files);
            } else {
                this.$emit("update:file", this.$refs[this.label].files[0]);
            }
        },
        removeFile(idx) {
            if (this.multiple) {
                _.pullAt(this.files, [idx]);
                this.$emit("update:files", this.files);
            } else {
                this.$emit("update:file", null);
            }
        },
    }
}
```

What should I add to have the possibility to open uploaded files directly in the browser?

Comment: open pdf on browser? something like pdf.js?

Comment: i tried to do it with window.open by taking file url and opening it in modal window. but in this flow a have to save it previously on backend-side too. i guess it ok, cause you can’t hold a file somewhere in the air